# Snack package seals animation with hooks

Tags: modeling, animation, transforms

I have the following model

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to make an animation where the top seal opens from one side to another, like when you open a snack package.

What I've tried so far is with hooks, I've added one hook from one side but when I move the hook it doesn't move the seal like a curve.

[image]

Any ideas? Also Is this the best way of achieving that animation with hooks? Thank you

Comment: hello, you could use bendy bones, the hard part will rather be how will you make the rip effect

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the comment. I never used bendy bones, I've tried to do the curve with SimpleDeform but it doesn't look much realistic https://i.imgur.com/spoiZWW.gif

Comment: put some bones all along and segment them so that when you animate you'll have something rather round?

Comment: could you please show what are the different steps of the tearing? it will help to find the best rigging solution

Comment: @moonboots the following animation resembles exactly of what I'm trying to achieve https://i.imgur.com/vUT2mvW.mp4. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bendy bones:

Create your armature, parent the package *With Empty Groups*, then assign the vertices to the groups they are supposed to be part of:

[image]

Display your armature as bendy bones, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to shrink the bone thickness in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Select each bone in *Edit* mode and segment them:

[image]

Animate:

[image]